# Mysql transaction rollback on failure in update

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, innodb

With a simple transaction as

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE posts SET status='approved' where post_id='id' AND status != 'approved';
.. other queries ...
COMMIT;
```

I want to perform the transaction only once when changing the status; but the above `UPDATE` will not give an error to rollback the transaction when no row is updated.

How can I limit the transaction to commit only if the row is updated (I mean the status is changed).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is in PHP (haven't tested, needs adapting to your situation):

```php
mysql_query('START TRANSACTION;')
mysql_query("UPDATE posts SET status='approved' where post_id='id' AND status != 'approved';");
if (mysql_affected_rows()){
    mysql_query('COMMIT');
} else {
    mysql_query('ROLLBACK');
}
```

Or, If you want to be clever and do it in SQL (using [`ROW_COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) and [`IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if-statement.html)):

```sql
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE posts SET status='approved' where post_id='id' AND status != 'approved';
SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO @affected_rows;
-- .. other queries ...
IF (affected_rows > 0) THEN
    COMMIT;
ELSE
    ROLLBACK;
END IF
```

Comment: Perfect! As a matter of fact, I am in PHP :)

Comment: @Ali I recommend updating tags than :P

Comment: Don't run "the other queries" then roll them back, that's a bit inneficient.  Just move them into the same code block as the COMMIT, so they only ever execute if needed (as opposed to always executing, then rolling them back sometimes).

Comment: @Dems very good point; I always try to avoid ROLLBACK and execute COMMIT if possible.

Comment: @Dems I assumed that he may have more queries which will affect records and which will matter... So the real condition would be: `(affected_1 + affected_2 + .... > 0) THEN` but in the case that this is the only relevant one, than you're of course right.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to do this in some sort of programming logic - maybe a stored procedure is best.

- `START TRANSACTION`
- run `UPDATE` query
- SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO some_variable
- `IF (some_variable>0) THEN` [run the other statements including `COMMIT`] `ELSE ROLLBACK`