# MYSQL If statement in transaction causing error

Tags: mysql, variables, transactions

I have the following MYSQL query:

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT sport_id INTO @a FROM sports WHERE sport_id = 2 FOR UPDATE;

UPDATE sports SET sport_name = 'Table Tennis' WHERE sport_id = @a;

if (@a > 1) then
    COMMIT;
ELSE
    ROLLBACK;
END IF;
```

The problem is that it returns an error at the if statement:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if (@a > 1) then COMMIT' at line 1

I've looked on stack overflow and there is an [answer showing a similar query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9327843/894792), written in pretty much the same way, but they are using the variable without an `@` symbol.  Removing the `@` for my query does not resolve the issue.

This is just a test query to try out some transactions using MYSQL, hence why the query seems a little pointless.  I'm a little stuck.

Answer (score 5):

MySQL doesn't recognize a statement beginning with the keyword `IF` as as a valid SQL statement.

The `IF` statement works only in the context of a compound statement (that is, a block of statements enclosed between `BEGIN` and `END`.  Currently, the compound statement is only supported in the context of a stored program (stored procedure, function or trigger.)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/begin-end.html

For testing, try...

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_test_transaction()
BEGIN
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION ROLLBACK;
  START TRANSACTION;

  -- whatever DML operations and SELECT statements you want to perform go here

  IF (1=1) THEN
    COMMIT;
  ELSE
    ROLLBACK;
  END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;

CALL usp_test_transaction;
```

(NOTE:  I am not advocating here that transactions be handled inside of stored procedure. My personal preference is to NOT do this, and instead handle transactions at a higher level. But the example above should work; I believe MySQL does support calling START TRANSACTION, COMMIT and ROLLBACK within the context of a stored procedure.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I've just tried putting a BEGIN END around the statement and it still comes up with the same error.  Can you recommend where I am to put the BEGIN and END statements to resolve the problem?

Comment: The BEGIN ... END syntax is used for writing compound statements, which can appear within stored programs (stored procedures and functions, triggers, and events).  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: Or you could try using the case operator
: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html