# Condition with SELECT and INSERT statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert, conditional-statements

i would like to make `SELECT` statement when the condition is equals to 1, so that will execute `INSERT` statement, when not, so it will not doing anything. What i think you can see below in my code.

```
SET @var = 1;

SELECT IF(@var = 1, 
    INSERT INTO tabulka VALUES('value1','name1'),
    0
)
```

Thanks

Comment: the condition or the number 3... is this a parameter you're passing in or is it something in another table or...?

Comment: Is *condition* a function a row data?

Comment: Ït is only example. I have more difficult query than this, but what i really need is when the variable is equals to 1 so that will execute 'Insert' statement. I don't know if i need 'if' condition.

Comment: See if answers to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485039/mysql-insert-where-query) help any.

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15766493/623952) explains that mysql only recognizes `if` when it is between a `begin` and `end` for a stored procedure (or trigger)... maybe there is another way to do what you want to do.  could you try explaining the whole situation?  are you using PHP at all?  is a stored procedure an option for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need an IF statement, not a SELECT.

```
if
    @var = 1
then
    insert into tabulka values('value1', 'name1');
end if
```

Comment: You need to provide more details on exactly what you're trying to do and what type of error you're getting.

Comment: SET var = 1;

IF
    var = 1
then
    insert into tabulka values('value1', 'name1')
end if

Comment: Yes when i execute this statement

Comment: You still haven't specified what error you're getting.  Anyway, here's an example of a simple IF statement in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f68b/1/1

Answer (score 0):

got it!

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66b33/1/0

```
create table test (
    int_field int, 
    str_field varchar(10) 
  );


set @var := 1;

insert into test 
   select  int_field, str_field 
   from    (select @var as int_field,
                   concat('var=',@var) as str_field 
           ) as temp
   where   @var=3;


set @var := 3;

insert into test 
   select  int_field, str_field 
   from    (select @var as int_field,
                   concat('var=',@var) as str_field 
           ) as temp
   where   @var=3; 


select * from test;
```

results in:

```
int_field      str_field
3              var=3
```