# mysql transaction using conditional commit or rollback

Tags: mysql, database, transactions

As part of my school project in databases, I'm having some problems with transaction. After a lot of reading, I've manage to put something together to update an account table. However, the IF-statement in the end fails, I believe.

I want to rollback, if the amount is less than 0 after withdrawing from the account, so I wonder if it's possible to use IF-statements like this? If not, any suggestions are most welcome! Thanks:)

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE withdrawFromAccount(pAccountId INT(11), pAmount DECIMAL(13,4))
BEGIN
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION ROLLBACK;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
START TRANSACTION;
SET @isValid = 0;
UPDATE `project3_account` SET `amount` = `amount` - pAmount WHERE `id` = pAccountId;
SELECT (CASE `amount` WHEN `amount` >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) INTO @isValid FROM `project3_account` WHERE `id` = pAccountId;
IF (@isValid = 1) THEN
COMMIT;
ELSE
ROLLBACK;
END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: When you says it fails, do u get any specific error? All can u provide specifics like what database you are using, version and other details...

Comment: No errors, but no changes to the table, so it doesn't seem to commit ..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL If statement in transaction causing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766336/mysql-if-statement-in-transaction-causing-error)