# don't insert in table if a error in MYSQL Transaction

Tags: mysql

I have a transaction in mysql which insert data into two tables (it works fine ):

```
    START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO tbl_chart (acode,adesc)  VALUES (2,'3');
    INSERT INTO tbl_pics  (ID ,adesc) VALUES (1,'1');
    COMMIT ;
```

But i want that if a error comes then the data should not be inserted in the particular tables . But now when error comes it shows it and also saves the data in table . I do not want this . i want that if error comes then it shows the error and do not save the data in tables . ? how to do it ?

Comment: Not sure what VB.NET and WPF have to do with this

Comment: No man just tell me how to do this in mysql ?

Comment: what error condition are you concerned about?  A SQL error? A VB error? A WPF/NET error?  You need to be more specific about KIND of errors you are talking about.

Comment: Don't run the transaction if an error occurs.

Comment: Plutonix  I am concerning about a SQL error .

Comment: I want that if a sql error happen then the data should not be saved .
for example if there is an error in second query then the first also should not be saved and vice versa

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327668/mysql-transaction-rollback-on-failure-in-update